# Sharing chained structure with memory mapped file from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++

Following my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47015984/sharing-memory-mapped-file-structure-between-c-and-c-sharp), I have been able to share string from C++ to C# thanks to this community.

However, I need to go one level above and I need to share chained structures from C++ to C# using memory mapping.

In an example scenario:

**My C++ structures:**

```
struct STRUCT_2
{
    char Name[260];
};

struct STRUCT_1
{
    void Init()
    {
        this->Count = 0;
        this->Index = 0;
    }

    DWORD Count;
    DWORD Index;
    STRUCT_2 Table[256];
};
```

**And me trying to "transfer" it to C#:**

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public unsafe struct STRUCT_2
{
   [FieldOffset(0)]
   public fixed char Name[260];
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public unsafe struct STRUCT_1
{
   void Init()
   {
     this.Count = 0;
     this.Index = 0;
   }
   [FieldOffset(0)]
   public uint Count;
   [FieldOffset(0)]
   public uint Index;
   [FieldOffset(100)]
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct, SizeConst = 256)]
   public STRUCT_2 Table;
}
```

This works partially, basically I can see the values from **Count** and **Index**, however I cannot see values or even get them in **STRUCT_2**.

I have tried to change:

```
public STRUCT_2[] Table;
```

But then the compiler tells me:

*"The specified Type must be a struct containing no references."*

So my question would be, how can you read structures within structures using *MemoryMappedFile* in C# ?

Advice, thoughts or examples are very welcomed.

**Update:**

**Complete testable code in C#:**

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public unsafe struct STRUCT_2
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public fixed byte Name[260];
            // Fix thanks to Ben Voigt
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public unsafe struct STRUCT_1
        {
            void Init()
            {
                this.Count = 0;
                this.Index = 0;
            }
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public uint Count;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public uint Index;
            [FieldOffset(100)]
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
            public STRUCT_2[] Table;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MemoryMappedFileSecurity CustomSecurity = new MemoryMappedFileSecurity();
            CustomSecurity.AddAccessRule(new System.Security.AccessControl.AccessRule<MemoryMappedFileRights>("everyone", MemoryMappedFileRights.FullControl, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));

            var mappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("Local\\STRUCT_MAPPING", 1024, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWriteExecute, MemoryMappedFileOptions.None, CustomSecurity, System.IO.HandleInheritability.Inheritable);

            using (var accessor = mappedFile.CreateViewAccessor())
            {
                STRUCT_1 data;

                accessor.Read<STRUCT_1>(0, out data); // ERROR !
                //The specified Type must be a struct containing no references.

                Console.WriteLine(data.Count);
                Console.WriteLine(data.Index);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is what the `fixed` keyword is for, unfortunately it can't be used with arrays of user-defined types, even if they are blittable.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/fixed-size-buffers

Comment: Yep, it will not allow me to read it... using CreateViewAccessor()

Comment: BTW the `FieldOffset` values you show are very wrong.  Right now, you're overlaying `Count` and `Index`, `union`-style, and then leaving far too much padding before the structure table starts.

Comment: Beyond that, the C# type corresponding to C++ `char` is `sbyte` not `char`.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks, I will review that.

Comment: Perhaps `UnmanagedType.ByValArray` would work better than `LPStruct`, because the C++ side doesn't use any pointer.

Comment: @BenVoigt unfortunately... I have tried everything I could find here, and everywhere else, I could not manage to do it....

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/9418410/103167

Comment: @BenVoigt Nope, that is different, plus the "answer" there does not actually work...

Comment: How is it different?  That code has a structure which contains an array of another structure.  Your code has the same, plus needs to access it through `MemoryMappedFile`.  Since none of the tries you've described look like the answer there, it's hard to know if you didn't make just a small mistake resulting in discarding the correct approach.  If you've been able to reproduce the success of that approach (in passing to a C++ function) and then found it didn't work for MemoryMappedFile, that would be important to tell everyone trying to help.

Comment: My code needs to work from managed C++ to C#, and it is a different scenario because when you try to use this in a MemoryMappedFile there are too many obstacles, for example you cannot even do "public simple_struct[] h;" like in the link you provided because you cannot read it...

Comment: Show your complete attempt using the approach shown in that answer, and say exactly what went wrong.  You can't build up piecemeal, `public simple_struct[] h` will fail (because you aren't allowed to have references) but `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=256)] public simple_struct[] h` doesn't have references, the data is held in place.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ok, I will post my complete attempt...

Comment: @BenVoigt Added code to see what I mean...

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33649565/103167  So the problem is that `MarshalAs` affects the marshalled memory layout but not the actual memory layout in .NET.... and `MemoryMappedFile` view accessors use the actual memory layout.  I guess you can make a fixed byte buffer of sufficient size and use `Marshal.PtrToStructure` to move your substructures in and out, or use pointers with `unsafe` keyword.  Also, the offsets are still wrong, as is the length of the memory-mapping.

Comment: It would have been so much better if "`fixed`" worked with blittable UDTs.

Comment: @Ben Voigt unfortunately I do not have enough experience in C# to produce a solution....

Comment: @BenVoigt I am still trying to find a fix, and I found that indeed you are correct, my FieldOffset are very wrong... I have no idea what are the correct values o.O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out.

Tested on Visual Studio 2017, Windows 7 x64.

Write and Read data works find.

It's also good study for me.

Take time on this.

Godspeed!

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct STRUCT_2
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 260)]
        public  byte[]  Name;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 4)]
    public struct STRUCT_1
    {
        void Init()
        {
            this.Count = 0;
            this.Index = 0;
        }
        public uint Count;
        public uint Index;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)] //! array size of 10.
        public STRUCT_2 [] Table;
    }

    static void test3()
    {

        MemoryMappedFileSecurity CustomSecurity = new MemoryMappedFileSecurity();
        CustomSecurity.AddAccessRule(new System.Security.AccessControl.AccessRule<MemoryMappedFileRights>
            ( "everyone"
            , MemoryMappedFileRights.FullControl
            , System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));

        using (var mappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("Local\\STRUCT_MAPPING"
                                                    , 10 * 1024
                                                    , MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWriteExecute
                                                    , MemoryMappedFileOptions.None
                                                    , CustomSecurity
                                                    , System.IO.HandleInheritability.Inheritable))
        { 
            using (var accessor = mappedFile.CreateViewAccessor())
            {
                //! test setting.
                int table_count = 5;

                //! write data.
                STRUCT_1 write_data;
                write_data.Index = 1;
                write_data.Count = 2;
                write_data.Table = new STRUCT_2[10];

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    write_data.Table[i].Name = new byte[260];
                    write_data.Table[i].Name[0] = (byte)i;
                }

                //! ----------------------------
                // Get size of struct
                int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(STRUCT_1));
                byte[] data = new byte[size];

                // Initialize unmanaged memory.
                IntPtr p = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

                // Copy struct to unmanaged memory.
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(write_data, p, false);

                // Copy from unmanaged memory to byte array.
                Marshal.Copy(p, data, 0, size);

                // Write to memory mapped file.
                accessor.WriteArray<byte>(0, data, 0, data.Length);

                // Free unmanaged memory.
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(p);
                p = IntPtr.Zero;

                //! ----------------------------------------------
                STRUCT_1 read_data;
                size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(STRUCT_1));
                data = new byte[size];

                // Initialize unmanaged memory.
                p = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);


                // Read from memory mapped file.
                accessor.ReadArray<byte>(0, data, 0, data.Length);

                // Copy from byte array to unmanaged memory.
                Marshal.Copy(data, 0, p, size);

                // Copy unmanaged memory to struct.
                read_data = (STRUCT_1)Marshal.PtrToStructure(p, typeof(STRUCT_1));

                // Free unmanaged memory.
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(p);
                p = IntPtr.Zero;


                Console.WriteLine(read_data.Index);
                Console.WriteLine(read_data.Count);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I will give this a try, as for now I need is Read.

Comment: I am writing from C++ this structure into mappedmemory, and I cannot get any values with your code...

Comment: I add to STRUCT_2 like so: increment Count and Index, and then: write_data.Table[write_data.Index].Name = "blablabla" ... from c++ of course.

Comment: Your solution is working, but something is going wrong because byte[] Name has data loss, basically I have 10 strings in Table and I get back only 2 and the rest: "?????????" ....

Comment: After tweaking the code to my needs, you have saved my DAY. Thank you for putting and end of 3 days in a row search and testing.

Comment: Now i see your writing, if any problem is there then send me the code, i'll take care of that. I'm glad you find a solution.